# GIT login via MySQL on Debian

Tags: debian, git

I have a SVN server set up where login can be done via virtual users (mysql).  Those users can login to another services like proftpd and postfix. No real users exists in the server.

The SVN login can be done via `libapache2-mod-svn`, `mod_authn_dbd` and a virtual host like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName svn.domain.com
    <Location />
                DAV svn
                SVNParentPath /path/to/svn
                SVNListParentPath On
                Require valid-user
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "SVN"
                AuthBasicProvider dbd
                AuthDBDUserPWQuery "select password from users where user = %s"
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I would like to create similiar set up but using GIT, is that possible?
I've read some articles like [this one](https://muras.eu/2012/04/06/git-server-with-apache-authentication-on-Ubuntu-Debian/), but they all login users that are set via htpasswd and I would like to login via database using the same users.

Comment: for git I use gitlab

Answer (score 0):

This setup should be possible. Typically you can use any Authentication Provider on any Virtualhost.

You can follow the tutorial and just remove all mentioned `Auth*` parameters and use the ones from your working SVN configuration.

It is also possible to create a custom Auth section, which can be re-used in many Vhosts. This provides e.g. a way to share caches for e.g. LDAP lookups between Vhosts. The related configuration parameter is `AuthnProviderAlias`.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_core.html#authnprovideralias

Comment: can you help me with some working code?